# The Method is undefined for the type Library(class)

Tags: java

How do i use the method Loanable to get setDueOn(calendar.getTime) and setLoanedTo(name) to function?

"Your library loan method should use the Loanable item that is passed in to set the due on and the loaned to.  You want to call those set methods on that passed in instance of Loanable.  "

I am getting the errors
The method setDueOn is undefined for the type library
The method setLoanedTo is undefined for the type library
Sorry for all the code.

```
package src.edu.htc.java1.library;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class Library {

    /* The collection of Media owned by the library */
    private ArrayList<Media> collection = new ArrayList<Media>();
    public void addToCollection(Media item) {
    collection.add(item);
    }

    public void loan(Loanable item,String name) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, item.getDaysToLoan()); // Now this is asking the helper how many days to loan for
        setDueOn(calendar.getTime()); 
        setLoanedTo(name);
        return(setdueOn(Loanable));     

    }

}
```

1

```
package src.edu.htc.java1.library;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * 
 */


/**
 * This class is used to test our library and media classes.
 *
 */
public class MediaTester {

    /**
     * This is the main test method
     * @param args - values passed in by the JVM when running
     * the application
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {



        Book myBook = new Book();
        myBook.setLibraryId(123456L);
        myBook.setLocation("Eden Prairie");
        myBook.setTitle("My Book Title");
        ArrayList<String> authorList = new ArrayList<String>();
        authorList.add("Joe Author");
        authorList.add("Jane Author");
        myBook.setAuthors(authorList);
        myBook.setCopyright("1984");
        myBook.setFormat("paperback");
        myBook.setNumberOfPages(385);
        myBook.setPublishers("Some Publisher");


        System.out.println(myBook);

        Movies myMovie = new Movies();
        myMovie.setTitle("Fargo");
        myMovie.setReleaseDate(2123);
        myMovie.setDirector("Matt Johnson");
        myMovie.setActors("Matt");
        myMovie.setMPAA_rating("R");
        ArrayList<String> actors = new ArrayList<String>();
        actors.add("Tom Hanks");


        System.out.println(myMovie);


        Games myGames = new Games();
        myGames.setTitle("Starcraft");
        myGames.setConsoleType("wii");
        myGames.setEsbnRatings("E");
        myGames.setReleaseDate("2012");
        myGames.setPublishers("Blizzard");

        System.out.println(myGames);


        Newspaper myPaper = new Newspaper();
         myPaper.setLibraryId(11122233L);
         myPaper.setLocation("St. Paul");
         myPaper.setTitle("Pioneer Press");



    ArrayList<Media> myMediaList = new ArrayList<Media>();
    myMediaList.add(myBook);
    myMediaList.add(myMovie);
    myMediaList.add(myGames);
    myMediaList.add(myPaper);
    Library myLibrary = new Library();

    for (Media item : myMediaList) {
    myLibrary.addToCollection(item);
    if (item instanceof Loanable) {
        myLibrary.loan((Loanable) item, "Mary");
        System.out.println(String.format("Item loaned out: %s",item));
        } else {
        System.out.println(
        String.format("Sorry you can't loan out this item: %s", item));
        }
        }

    }
    }
```

2

```
package src.edu.htc.java1.library;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

    import java.util.Date;

/**
 * 
 */

/**
 * This class represents an item in our library's collection.
 *
 */
public abstract class Media {

    public static final int STANDARD_LOAN_DAYS = 14;  

    private long libraryId;
    private String title;
    private String location;
    private String loanedTo;
    private Date dueOn;


    @Override
       public String toString() {

           StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

           builder.append("{");

           builder.append(this.getClass().getSimpleName());

           builder.append(": ");

           builder.append("[id=").append(libraryId);

           builder.append("], [title=").append(title);

           builder.append("], [loanedTo=").append(loanedTo);




           if (getDueOn() != null) {

            builder.append("], [dueOn=");

               SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

               builder.append(formatter.format(getDueOn()));

           }

           builder.append("]");

           builder.append(toStringHelper());

           builder.append("}");

           return builder.toString();

       }

    public long getLibraryId() {
        return libraryId;
    }
    public void setLibraryId(long libraryId) {
        this.libraryId = libraryId;
    }
    protected String toStringHelper() {
        return " ";
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public String getLoanedTo() {
        return loanedTo;
    }
    public Date getDueOn() {
        return dueOn;
    } 
    public void setDueOn(Date dueOn) {
        this.dueOn = dueOn;
    }
    public void setLoanedTo(String loanedTo) {
        this.loanedTo = loanedTo;
    }



}
```

3

Comment: I think your `Media` class should implement a `Loanable` interface like so `public abstract class Media implements Loanable {`

Comment: If you're going to dump a lot of code on us, please make some effort to make it a bit more compact and remove unneeded blank lines and comments etc. Then people will be more likely to actually look through it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Media class might need to implement the Loanable interface like pointed out in the comments if the inheriting classes don't, and then this method:

```
public void loan(Loanable item,String name) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, item.getDaysToLoan()); // Now this is asking the helper how many days to loan for
    setDueOn(calendar.getTime()); 
    setLoanedTo(name);
    return(setdueOn(Loanable));     
}
```

has a few errors that need to be fixed:

1. If you declare a method `void` it means it can't (and shouldn't) return anything, so don't use any return statement in it.
2. The method calls `setDueOn` and `setLoanedTo` needs to be called on a specific object, in this case `item`. At the moment you're trying to call methods by that name local to the `Library` class, where they don't exist.
3. If you look at the method `setDueOn(Date dueOn)` you'll note that it expects a date, not a class or interface name...

After corrections the method might look like this:

```
public void loan(Loanable item,String name) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, item.getDaysToLoan());
    item.setDueOn(calendar.getTime()); 
    item.setLoanedTo(name);
}
```

There might be other issues, but the code is really a bit too long to browse through...